# angular-datatable minimize watchers

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following with npm:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.6.4",
    "datatables.net": "1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "1.5.3",
    "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "1.5.3",
    "angular-datatables": "0.6.2",
    // and more that is not question related
}
```

When I now create a DataTable like angular-datatables shows in the examples, everything is working great.
But I get a lot of watchers and that is my concern.

A normal table with an id, a firstname and a surname column, like in the example, gets around 250 watchers when only displaying 10 rows.
550 watchers when displaying 25 rows and 1050 watchers on 50 rows
(a blank page with only the menu has around 10 watchers in my example).

How can I reduce the number of watchers in the angular-datatables v0.6.2?
From what I understand in the jQuery DataTable wrapper, it renders the rows using $compile. So there would be no need to bind the data with watchers.
When new data is fetched serverside for example, the table would be re-rendered using $compile and not ng-repeat.

So the data could be static, but I do not know where to fix this.
Or do I misunderstand the workflow?
What can I do to minimize the watchers?

Thanks for the help and greetings

PS.: I am using the code from the server-side example from [here](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/serverSideProcessing)

Comment: Start from posting your table example

Comment: I am using the code from the server-side example from [here][1] with no changes. only my own AngularJS setup. But clean with a watcher counter in order to see how many watchers there are.


  [1]: http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/serverSideProcessing

Comment: check http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/disableDeepWatchers
provide your own custom templates with reduced amount of watchers or one time watchers with :: syntax. (http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/angularDirectiveInDOM)

Comment: disabling deep watchers does not change the watchers amount in angular-datatable. already tried it. and wrapping with a directive sounds interesting, but then I would render the table and alter it after.